# What are the values?

Tags: c, debugging, variables, ide, watch

I'm trying to learn C and have been trying a few exercises in a book I have found on the internet.

This question will probably be easy for you experts, What are the values displayed in the watch window when I watch some of the variables.  I am referring to its state BEFORE a value is assigned to the variable. They are usually long numbers with about 10 digits and sometimes negative.

I know this may seem a silly question, but I am curious as to what they are.  At first I thought they were addresses.

Comment: Most likely you are seeing whatever was in memory before the variable was initialized.

Comment: Values of default-intialized variables having scalar types are indeterminate.

Comment: this is related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597405/what-happens-to-a-declared-uninitialized-variable-in-c-does-it-have-a-value

Comment: Briefly: garbage...

Answer (score 2):

Since memory is not reset to a particular value when it is deallocated or reallocated, you will see whichever value was left there by the last code that was using that memory.

This can sometimes be a security issue. For example, if if that memory contained a password or other sensitive information. Hence for certain applications, it is important to zero-out the memory before freeing it.

Answer (score 2):

Before you assign a value to a variable, it has whatever happened to be in that memory previously. It's very likely that the memory for a variable in one function was used for a variable of a different type in some other function. If the previous use was for a `float` or pointer, and now you're using it for an `int`, the value will look very random.